# React native: Always running component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I don't know actually, how to name this question!

I've a JS file in react native that fetches data from server and compares it to local database. i need this to run simultaneously, how can i achieve that? when app starts, that should run, changing views (navigation to other components) should not destroy it, it should still be running.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are explaining a design pattern of something called: [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Here's how to do it:

```
let instance = null;

class Singleton{  
    constructor() {
        if(!instance){
              instance = this;
        }

        // to test whether we have singleton or not
        this.time = new Date()

        return instance;
      }
}
```

Testing singleton
On above class we have defined a time property to make sure we have singleton working properly.

```
 let singleton = new Singleton()
 console.log(singleton.time);

 setTimeout(function(){
   let singleton = new Singleton();
   console.log(singleton.time);
 },4000);
```

If it prints the same time for both the instances, it means we have a working singleton.

Now, you can load your server data asynchronously inside the singleton and do whatever you'd like to do with it. Anytime you try to access the singleton class, it will be the same instance and it will not be instantiated more than once. In other words, it will not be destroyed.

Source: http://amanvirk.me/singleton-classes-in-es6/

Comment: Honestly, i didn't get your point. I've found https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers , not sure if it's what i'm looking for. Btw, thanks for your answer.

Comment: As far as I understood, you wanted to have a single instance of a class, and you want this instance to be kept alive the whole lifecycle of the app. This thing is called a singleton. Any properties inside this class will be persistent no matter how much you re-instantiate it.  In your case, you'll load your server data asynchronously inside the singleton class, and it will persist being there.

Comment: @Ataomega BTW, the workers are for background tasks that are CPU intensive.  Workers run in a different thread than the main app, therefore it doesn't lock the app.  I don't think it's the proper solution, but it could work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but this might help somebody else,

> One option is to make a singleton class.
> But the other option is to create a container for your Navigations file. > Navigation container is just a normal component whose child is the main
> navigator component.

> The code you've in navigation container is running all the time.

> I use navigation container like this..

```
     export default function App() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                    <NavigationContainer />
            </Provider>
           );
         }
```

> And from this navigation container i return the navigator component like > this

```
    return (
 <AuthNavigator ref={navRef} />
    );
```