# React Native Websocket outside access

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket

Im trying to send an answer to my websocket-server from a component which does not contain the websocket. My Websocket server looks like this:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws:// URL');
    ws.onmessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
    ...
    }
```

How can I pass the "var ws" to another class or component. Or is it possible to make the websocket globally accessable? 
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I think first you should connect to websocket, once connected then only you can send. test it in local system. like give path as ws://127.0.0.1:8100

Comment: What you're using for navigation is relevant

Comment: I'm using react navigation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution with help from this question in stackoverflow:

visit:

[React native: Always running component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740588/react-native-always-running-component)

I created a new class WebsocketController like this:

```
    let instance = null;

    class WebsocketController{
        constructor() {
            if(!instance){
               instance = this;
            }
            this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://URL');
            return instance;
        }
    }

    export default WebsocketController
```

And then in my other class where I need my websocket I just called it like this:

```
    let controller = new WebsocketController();
    var ws = controller.ws;
```

Comment: You're code made me to look further. I found this link which I used as an inspiration. https://blog.parsable.com/websocket-connections-and-ui-with-react-nuclearjs-and-immutablejs-7fd341dd050b

Comment: this is called singleton

Answer (score 0):

websocket connection

keep this code in some file, name it with .js extenstion. ex: websocket.js

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:8100});

wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        client.send(msg);
    });
};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    // Store the remote systems IP address as "remoteIp".
    var remoteIp = ws.upgradeReq.connection.remoteAddress;
    // Print a log with the IP of the client that connected.
    console.log('Connection received: ', remoteIp);

    ws.send('You successfully connected to the websocket.');

    ws.on('message',wss.broadcast);
});
```

In your app/website side. create .js file. Ex: client.js

```
var SERVER_URL = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8100';
var ws;

function connect() {
  //alert('connect');
    ws = new WebSocket(SERVER_URL, []);
    // Set the function to be called when a message is received.
    ws.onmessage = handleMessageReceived;
    // Set the function to be called when we have connected to the server.
    ws.onopen = handleConnected;
    // Set the function to be called when an error occurs.
    ws.onerror = handleError;

}

function handleMessageReceived(data) {
    // Simply call logMessage(), passing the received data.
    logMessage(data.data);
}

function handleConnected(data) {
    // Create a log message which explains what has happened and includes
    // the url we have connected too.
    var logMsg = 'Connected to server: ' + data.target.url;
    // Add the message to the log.
    logMessage(logMsg)

    ws.send("hi am raj");
}

function handleError(err) {
    // Print the error to the console so we can debug it.
    console.log("Error: ", err);
}

function logMessage(msg) {
    // $apply() ensures that the elements on the page are updated
    // with the new message.
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        //Append out new message to our message log. The \n means new line.
        $scope.messageLog = $scope.messageLog + msg + "\n";
    });

}
```

Please let me know if you face any issue with this code

Comment: actually it didn't recognize this : var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

Comment: install this: npm install ws

Comment: I found another solution, see below I posted an answer

Comment: Ok you can use any solutions.

Comment: ya. you are welcome. I am also working on websocket. you can ask if you stuck anywhere in code